# vba access query with variables

Tags: vba, ms-access

> I get the runtime error 3141 which says the SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect. On user form click, I'm trying to use a loop where multiple fields within a query are defined using variable inputs. Where am I going wrong here?

```
Private Sub Calculate_Click()
Dim db As Database
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim WPmonthly As String ' field name for monthly written premium
Dim UPRmonthly As String ' field name for monthly unearned premium
Dim EPmonthly As String ' field name for monthly earned premium
Dim runningDate As Date
Dim useDateLower As Date
Dim useDateUpper As Date
Dim qry As dao.QueryDef

Months = Me.YearsBack * 12 + Month(Me.ValDate)

If Me.Period = "monthly" Then

    Set db = CurrentDb

    Set qry = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("MyQuery")
    Debug.Print qry.SQL ' shows the SQL from MyQuery

    For x = 1 To Months

    runningDate = Format(DateAdd("m", -x + 1, Me.ValDate), "mm yyyy")
    useDateLower = runningDate
    useDateUpper = Format(DateAdd("m", -x + 2, Me.ValDate), "mm yyyy")
    WPmonthly = "WP M" & Month(runningDate) & " " & Year(runningDate)
    EPmonthly = "EP M" & Month(runningDate) & " " & Year(runningDate)
    UPRmonthly = "UPR M" & Month(runningDate) & " " & Year(runningDate)
    qry.SQL = "SELECT IIf([tblEPdata]![IssueDate]>" & useDateLower & ",IIf([tblEPdata]![IssueDate]<" & useDateUpper & ",[tblEPdata]![GrossPremium])) AS " & WPmonthly & " FROM tblEPdata;"

    Next

    qry.Close

End If
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would change is this line:

```
qry.SQL = _
"SELECT IIf([IssueDate] > #" & useDateLower & "#," & _
"IIf([IssueDate] < #" & useDateUpper & "#," & _
"[GrossPremium])) AS [" & WPmonthly & "] FROM tblEPdata;"
```

Also need brackets around WPmonthly.  I would also try changing using bangs instead of periods (Me!Period).

Answer (score 0):

by seing your query i think that is the format for `Dates` should be between `''` and `yyyymmdd` or `yyyy-mm-dd` format and for the last `;` in the query statement.

You have something like:

```
useDateLower = 01/05/2016
```

`Excel` understand it but SQL does not, so, you must inclose your dates with `''` or `##` and your query ends like:

```
... [tblEPdata]![IssueDate]> '' " & useDateLower & " '' ,IIf([tb...
```

and you can add an Alias to your table.

```
qry.SQL = "SELECT IIf([TBL].[IssueDate]> ''" & useDateLower & _ 
                "'',IIf([TBL].[IssueDate]< ''" & useDateUpper & _  
                "'',[TBL].[GrossPremium])) AS " & WPmonthly & _  
         " FROM tblEPdata AS [TBL]"
```

Comment: So after fixing the syntax, the code still doesn't do what I want it to. Only one column (the last one created) displays in the query I create instead of having one for each month. How would I do that?

Comment: @zkhan I realize that you missing FALSE values `SELECT IIF([Condition], TRUE = IIF([Condition], TRUE= [GrossPremium] , Missing False), Missing False)`